# Add random users to groups from CSV file

Tags: powershell, random, powershell-cmdlet

I have a question, i'm adding users from a csv file to some groups, in this ex. it's MAX. 3 users/group.But what I want is, that I have 10 groups and then adding the random users from the csv file to the groups, then maybe i got 7 groups with 4 users and then last 3 with 3 users and thats OK.

But how do I changes this script, from just adding 3 users/group, to adding users to the "hardcoded" 10 groups, from the csv file?

ATM. I got this:

```
$deltager = Import-Csv C:\Users\Desktop\liste.csv

$holdstr = 3

$maxTeams = [math]::ceiling($deltager.Count/$holdstr)


$teams = @{}


$shuffled = $deltager | Get-Random -Count $deltager.Count


$shuffled | ForEach-Object { $i = 1 }{

$teams["$([Math]::Floor($i / $holdstr))"] += @($_.Navn)

$i++

}


$Grupper = $teams | Out-String

Write-Host $Grupper
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the remainder/modulo operator `%` to "wrap around" the group index, then simply add one user at a time for optimum distribution:

```bsh
# define number of groups
$numberOfTeams = 10

# read participant records from csv
$participants = Import-Csv C:\Users\Desktop\liste.csv

# create jagged array for the team rosters
$teams = ,@() * $numberOfTeams

# go through participant list, add to "next" group in line
$index = 0
$participants |%{
  $teams[$index++ % $numberOfTeams] += @($_.Navn)
}
```

If you want to randomize the order of participants, simply sort the list randomly before populating the groups:

```bsh
$participants = Import-Csv C:\Users\Desktop\liste.csv |Sort-Object {Get-Random}
```

Each item in `$teams` will be another array of names, so to enumerate them:

```bsh
0..$teams.Length |%{
  Write-Host "Team $($_+1):" $($teams[$_] -join ', ')
}
```

Comment: Hi Mathias
If I add a write-host $teams, then I get a list of all the participants, in random order, but can't see what group from 1 to 10, they are in.

Comment: @ThomasBøgPetersen Updated the answer to show how you _could_ enumerate the inner arrays (the individual team rosters basically)

Comment: Thx alot, and oc